# Storing openAI embeddings to postgres in Java

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, openai-api

I can't store embeddings to postgresql database.

I am computing embeddings in Java using Open AI api.

```
EmbeddingResult embeddingResult = openAIService.createEmbedding(embeddingInput);
List<Double> embeddingsList = embeddingResult.getData().get(0).getEmbedding();
```

It returns me `List<Double>`.

Now I need to store it to Postgres database. I need to store it to one column, as a vector(1536).

[image]

I tried to create my own class – AttributeConverter so that Hibernate can handle `List<Double>` as a PostgreSQL array/vector.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ListToDoubleArrayConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Double>, Double[]> {

    @Override
    public Double[] convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Double> attribute) {
        if (attribute == null || attribute.isEmpty()) {
            return new Double[0];
        }
        return attribute.toArray(new Double[attribute.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Double> convertToEntityAttribute(Double[] dbData) {
        if (dbData == null || dbData.length == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return Arrays.asList(dbData);
    }
}
```

And use it

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "explicit_questions")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ExplicitQuestion implements IBaseModel {

    ...

    @Convert(converter = ListToDoubleArrayConverter.class)
    private List<Double> embedding;
```

I got:
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "embedding" is of type vector but expression is of type bytea
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

---

I tried

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@Type(type = "jsonb")
private List<Double> embedding;
```

I was able to store the embedding, but I wasn't able to fetch.

---

I also tried define my own type.

```
@TypeDef(
    name = "double-array",
    typeClass = DoubleArrayType.class
)
public class ExplicitQuestion... {

    @Type(type = "double-array")
    @Column(
        name = "embeddings", 
        columnDefinition = "double precision[]"
    )
    private List<Double> embeddings;

}
```

But nothing works.

I use PagingAndSortingRepository from spring for auto generating SQLs. I also tried to write my own:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE explicit_questions set embedding = :embedding where id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
void createEmbedding(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("embedding") Double[] embedding);
```

I know I can store the embeddings to separate table, but then it is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here [What JPA + Hibernate data type should I use to support the vector extension in a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553746/what-jpa-hibernate-data-type-should-i-use-to-support-the-vector-extension-in-a)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
public class ExplicitQuestion implements IBaseModel {

    ...

    @Basic
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(name = "embedding", columnDefinition = "vector")
    private List<Double> embedding;
}
```